# Optimal interval between workouts

Tags: bodybuilding, muscle-mass, muscle-recovery

I read somewhere that after breaking your muscles apart (f.e. by working out) they start to repair until the muscles reach their new maximum volume/strentgh.
All information which is not new for me, but then the author said something interresting in my opinium. He/she said that after reaching the maximum volume/strength the muscles start to decrease again, I figured the body would probably be consuming the muscle, if it lacks on protein. So he/she implied that one should workout again at that moment, not earlier and not later, in order to experience optimal progress.

Ok, seems all very logical to me, but I still have a few questions about this:

1. Is this true?
2. If one is following a strict nutrition program, will the muscles still descrease? Or just slower? And what approximate period does it take to get back to the old level (I know this differs per person, but I would like to make a approximation)?
3. How do you know you are at your optimal interval to workout again?

Comment: 1.yes; 2:[read this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16233/is-once-per-week-training-enough-for-building-muscle); 3:[and this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14129/what-is-the-ideal-number-of-days-of-rest-to-take-every-week-for-a-beginner-inter/14132#14132)

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla Thanks, that does answer my questions partially. I still would like to see a full answer to every question though.